# write a csv file from a list of lists using the same indexes

Tags: python, csv

So I have some data in the form

```
headers = ['date', 'time', 'service', 'info']
csvData = [headers, findDate, findTime, findService, findInfo]
```

where the data looks like:

```
[[date, time, service, info],[a1, a2, a3, a4],[b1, b2, b3, b4].[c1, c2, c3, c4],[d1, d2, d3, d4]]
```

and I want it to look like this when it is wrote to the csv file:

```
date, time, service, info
a1, b1, c1, d1
a2, b2, c2, d2
a3, b3, c3, d3
a4, b4, c4, d4
```

I know I need to iterate through the file and I have tried various things:

which all turn out like this:

```
date, time , service, info
a1,a2,a3,a4
b1,b2,b3,b4
c1,c2,c3,c4
d1,d2,d3,d4
```

I know there is a csv module but I've looked at it and I don't think it can do something like this. Unless I'm just looking in the wrong places.

Comment: You should read about [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)

Comment: Ok after zipping - it's better but the headers are now at the start of each row going down the left - they need to be at the top of the columns. I'll mess with zip some more . thanks.

Comment: I suspect that you should remove the headers before zipping

Comment: I'll remove them and then zip and then write the headers and then write the rest.